# ASP.Net Core 2 and Windows authentication with static files

Tags: single-page-application, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

I am deploying a SPA (React) app using ASP.Net Core and IIS
I need to use windows authentication to call an API from the UI
Does anyone know how I can insert the appropriate headers into my pages for using Windows Authentication?